# Android studio SQL cant find table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using `SQLiteDatabase` and i've got a weird problem - when im trying to `SELECT * FROM` table its gives me this:

```
no such table: test_table (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM test_table
```

but when i insert to the same table, no `Exception` is sent.
This is my code:

The method that gets all the data from the table:

```
public List<Test> GetAllTests()
{
    List<Test> tests =new ArrayList<Test>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TEST_TABLE;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            test.setSubjectID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT_ID)));

            String dateString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEST_DATE));
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = format.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            test.setDate(date);
            test.setGrade(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEST_GRADE)));

            tests.add(test);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return tests;
}
```

The method that insert data to the same table(no Exception):

```
public long InsertTest(Test test)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_SUBJECT_ID,test.getSubjectID());
    values.put(KEY_TEST_DATE,test.getDate().toString());
    return db.insert(TEST_TABLE,null,values);
}
```

The code that inserts and get the data:

```
Test test = new Test(testSubjectID.getSelectedItemPosition(),date);
AddTestToList(test);
try {
    dbManager.InsertTest(test);
    List<Test> tests = dbManager.GetAllTests();
    for (Test test:tests)
    {
        AddTestToList(test);
    }
}catch (Exception e){Log.d("MSG_ERROR",e.toString());}
```

Comment: uninstall your app and install again

Comment: That fixed it :)

Comment: Uninstall and install back ?

Comment: Yea haha it worked

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing again?

Comment: @uğuraydın yes.

Comment: @uğuraydın Uninstalling good approach ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it needs to be refreshed.

Comment: consider mark one of the answer that you feel helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FYI**

- **`App uninstall`** is not good approach . If your APP is on **`PLAYSTORE`** then ?

You should Use [**`onUpgrade`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) for avoid **`DATA LOSS`** .

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation
>   should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else
>   it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

**How ?**

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Updating table from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);


        if (oldVersion < 3){ // Here I SET 3. You should use your DB version . When-ever **`adding table`**  please increase DB version .
            db.execSQL(ALTER_USER_TABLE_1);
            db.execSQL(ALTER_USER_TABLE_2);
        }

    }
```

**`ALTER TABLE`**

```
private static final String ALTER_USER_TABLE_1 =  "ALTER TABLE test_table ADD FIELD_NAME TEXT";
private static final String ALTER_USER_TABLE_2 = "ALTER TABLE test_table ADD FIELD_NAME2 TEXT";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an older version of the database on your device, which does not have the `test_table` table.

**Solution: Uninstall your app and install again**